# How can i test an observable that has pipe and map?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I'm assigning values to this variables inside ngOnInit:

```
this.simStatsList$ = this.sideMenuService.getSimStatsList();
this.currentStation$ = this.simStatsList$.pipe(
            map(station => station.find((station: ISimStats) => station.stationName === this.authService.userStation)),
                ) as Observable<ISimStats>;
```

This is my test:

```
it('should select userStation as currentStation', () => {
        component.currentStation$.subscribe((response) => {
            expect(response).toEqual(
                { stationName: 'test', stats: { open: 0, down: 0, preflight: 0 } }
            );
        });
    });
```

It passes but is not covering the map function from rxjs. Also im providing sideMenuService and AuthService as mocked values and this is my mock. I'm missing something but i don't know what is it.

```
export const mockSideMenuService = {
    getSimStatsList: () =>
        of([
            { stationName: 'test', stats: { open: 0, down: 0, preflight: 0 } },
            { stationName: 'test1', stats: { open: 1, down: 1, preflight: 1 } }
        ] as ISimStats[])
}

export const mockAuthService = {
       userStation: 'test'
}
```

Could you help me to cover the whole code?

Comment: You can make the function you pass to the `map` operator a named (and static, if you like) function. It will be pure, so very easy to test, independently from the Observable.

Answer (score 0):

After @will alexander comment i did some change and it worked:

First, pass the function to the sideMenuService and recieve needed data as parameters:

```
side-menu.service.ts

getCurrentSimStats(
    simStatsList$: Observable<ISimStats[]>,
    currentStation: string): Observable<ISimStats> {

    return simStatsList$.pipe(
        map((station) => station.find((station: ISimStats) => station.stationName === currentStation))) as Observable<ISimStats>;
}
```

Then my component test coverage passed as 100% but the sideMenuService wasn't so i wrote this small test on service spec file:

```
side-menu.service.spec.ts

it('should getCurrentStation', () =>{
        service.getCurrentSimStats(of(mockSideMenuService.mockSimStatsResponse), 'test').subscribe((res) => {
            expect(res).toEqual(mockSideMenuService.mockCurrentSimStatsResponse);
        });
    })
```

After this, everything worked and tests are passing!